# Dynamic link from pivot table to change value on another table in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pivot-table

I have an overview table that is a pivot table with changing values (depending on the filtering).
I want to link from each row of the table (OverviewTable) to another table (DetailedView) in the same spreadsheet.
Column A of the pivot table stores the name of a person and should be copied to A1 on the second spreadsheet (DetailedView).
I understood so far that links from cells are not possible to trigger scripts. Right? Unless I created images that look like cells.
The problem is, that the number of values in the pivot table changes while filtering.
Any ideas on how to solve that issue are greatly appreciated.
Best
Frank J.

[Pivottable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wut2h.png)
[image]

[SingleView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSrxL.png)

[image]

If I click on "open in Single View" next to the pivottable it should copy the value from the first column (the name of the person) to the SingleView table.

The Single View in Column B6 (and the others) works like this: =DGET(TableView!A:CN;A6;{"Name";A$1}). The Single view page is necessary because the TableView contains some fields with a lot of text which is not readable in a classic table format.

I tried this, but the effect is that if I come back to the RatingsExplorer-Sheet, the selection is still in the row 24 and therefor it immediately jumps back to the SingleView. But I didn't find a way to switch the active cell to A1 before switching the active table to the SingleView.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
 
  if ((sh.getName()=="RatingsExplorer") && ((col=="24") / (col="48")))
  {
     var nameval = sh.getRange(row,col-22).getValue();
       var spreadsheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
         spreadsheet2.getRange(1,1).setValue("huhu"); //here I tried so set the active cell of RatingsExplorer to A1, but it didnt work
         var sheet2 = spreadsheet2.getSheetByName('RatingsExplorer');
    spreadsheet2.setActiveSheet(sheet2); //here I tried so set the active cell of RatingsExplorer to A1, but it also didnt work
     var spreadsheet=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SingleView');
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(nameval);
 
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
   
    
  }
}
```

Comment: At this point this question is a little broad to create a good mental image of the problem.  Perhaps you can discuss the characteristics of the  overview table that would link to the detailed view and provide several concrete examples.  This might come in the form of several diagrams with additional text to explain the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it likes this:

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if ((sh.getName()=="RatingsExplorer") && ((col=="24") || (col=="48")))
  {
    e.range.offset(0,1).activate();
     var nameval = sh.getRange(row,col-22).getValue();
      

     var spreadsheet=  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('SingleView');
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(nameval);
 
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(sheet);
   
    
  }
}
```